# VBA result record of loop with solver

Tags: vba, loops, excel, solver

I want to use solver to optimize a system of non-linear problem. For each loop, I want to record the changing cells result, which are Cells(5,4),Cells(5,5),Cells(5,6),Cells(5,7). But my code seem like only record the first loop result.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim lIncrement As Long
lIncrement = 10
For Counter1 = 10 To 12
For Counter2 = 10 To 20 Step lIncrement
Cells(18, 2) = Counter1
    Cells(11, 2) = Counter2
    SolverOk SetCell:="$H$16", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$5:$G$5", _
        Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$H$16", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$5:$G$5", _
        Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    Cells(21 + Counter1, 1 + Counter2 / lIncrement).Value = Cells(5, 4) & "," & Cells(5, 5) & "," & Cells(5, 6) & "," & Cells(5, 7)
    Next Counter2
Next Counter1

End Sub
```

Comment: BIRDSVIEW: After the line `SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1` add this line `DoEvents`